# Qual o termo correto, palavra chave ou palavra reservada?

Tags: terminologia

Na programação temos certas "palavras especiais" que fazem coisas específicas.

Essas palavras são popularmente chamadas de palavras-chave ou palavras reservadas.

Qual o termo correto para essas palavras?

Exemplos: `if`, `double`, `while`, `this`, `interface`, entre outras.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ambos estão corretos porque elas querem dizer coisas diferentes para a mesma coisa, ou seja, palavra reservada significa que aquela palavra não pode ser usada para identificadores no seu código, a linguagem proíbe isto porque ela **possivelmente** tem uso para elas. Já a palavra-chave é aquela que indica que faz algo especial no código. As palavras costumam ser as mesmas, mas tem exceções.

Podem existir palavras reservadas que não são usadas efetivamente pela linguagem e por isso não podem ser consideradas palavra-chave (ex.: `goto` do Java). Existem palavras-chave que são contextuais, por isso em certos contextos elas não são reservadas (ex.: `where` ou `value` do C#).

Existem linguagens que permitem que todas as palavras-chave possam ser usadas livremente, portanto não possuem palavras reservadas, já que o udo em identificador consegue ser feito de forma não ambígua.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).